# Численные методы. Метод итераций

Tags: java, математика, численные-методы

Выполняю задание по численным методам. Нужно с помощью метода итераций найти корень уравнения x^3-12x-5=0.
После преобразования в итерационный вид по методичке (x+(12*x-Math.pow(x,3)-5)/36) не могу получить Х приближённый к 3.65, 3.23 получается, но как-то далековато.

Помогите.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Метод_Итераций {

    public double x, epsilon, d, x1, xR;
    public int iteration = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Метод_Итераций Zadacha3 = new Метод_Итераций();
        Zadacha3.vvod();
        Zadacha3.Proverka();
        Zadacha3.start();
    }

    public void vvod() {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = System.in;
            Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            System.out.println("Введите значение начальное значение х");
            x = Double.parseDouble(bufferedReader.readLine());
            System.out.println("Введите значение точности е");
            epsilon = Double.parseDouble(bufferedReader.readLine());
            xR = x;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("-----Ошибка ввода");
            vvod();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            double x1 = 0;
            BigDecimal f1 = new BigDecimal(epsilon);
            while (true) {
                x1 = f(x);
                d = Math.abs(x1 - x);
                iteration += 1;
                BigDecimal f2 = new BigDecimal(d);
                if (f2.compareTo(f1) < 1) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    x = x1;
                }
            }
            print(x1, d, iteration);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("С этой начальной точки корней найти не удалось");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    static double f(double x) {
        return (x+(12*x-Math.pow(x,3)-5)/36);
        //корни -3.23 -0.42 3.65
    }

    public void print(double a, double b, int c) {
        DecimalFormat dF = new DecimalFormat("#.############");
        System.out.println("\n" + "х = " + dF.format(a)
                + "\nпогрешность приближения = " + dF.format(b)
                + "\nИтерация " + iteration + "");
    }

    public void Proverka() {
        if (x <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Условие х <= 0 нарушено");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас как минимум неверный итерационный вид (кстати, даже простой `pow(12.*x+5.,1./3.)` нормально отработает... впрочем, многое зависит от начального приближения).

Смотрите сами — у вас один знак потерян: `12x` и `5` в исходном задании с одним знаком, а у вас в формуле — с разными...

Вопросов больше нет?

Вот исправленный код: https://ideone.com/qUwMG8